# Update channel entry

Tags: add-on-development, entry

I'm new to EE.
Actually I have some problem updating a entry.
This is my code:

```
    ee()->load->library('api'); 
    $data_item = array(
    'stock' => '4'
);

ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings(7, $data_item);

if(ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data_item, NULL, 31, TRUE) === FALSE)
    {
       (display error message)
    }
```

where I am wrong?
many thanks in advance !

Comment: are you sure that you need autosave = TRUE (table _channel_entries_autosave)? Try ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($data_item, NULL, 31, FALSE)

Comment: It does not work. It seems that the method does not return any of the expected values ​​(TRUE, FALSE) :-(

Comment: There are a lot of potential issues at play here. Firstly permissions. The channel entries API requires an EE session to be active for it to work. So, if you're doing this via cron or a situation where it's not a logged in user, you have to fake the session.

Comment: Also, you should know that when you use `save_entry` to update and existing entry, you have to pass all the field data, not just what you're changing - otherwise the existing field data will be deleted.

Comment: This is very boring. I tried Open Api, but this extension use deprecated functions for DB actions...